# System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings not accessible in production

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, desktop-application, windows

I have a windows desktop application from which a web application is starting.

```
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string url = string.Format("http://localhost:49916/Express/Login.aspx?yek@soh={0}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HK"].ToString());

           Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url);
           this.Close();
       }
```

It is working fine on my machine. I then created a setup program to install it, which worked fine however when I run my newly installed program on the production machine I get the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at HospitalClient_App.Home.Home_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

If I change the line

```
 Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url);
```

to

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe","http://localhost:49916/Express/Login.aspx?yek@soh=6775228");
```

then the program works.

My app.config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="HK" value="PRO2"/>
        <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

How can I solve this issue? What could be causing the problem?

Comment: And what does your app.config's appSettings section look like?

Comment: <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="HK" value="PRO2"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

This is my app.config file

Comment: Thanks for editing my question.. It would be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At run time, the filename of the configuration file being read, is **NOT** app.config.  It is applicationname.extension.config.

For example: If your running application.exe, the name of your configuration file would be application.exe.confiig.  The file should be in the same directory as your application.

Answer (score 2):

The only place my psychic debugger sees a potential NRE is here:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HK"].ToString()
```

(Which is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings.aspx), use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]`).

The fact that it throws there will teach you that no Appsetting with key `HK` could be found, causing `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HK"]` to return `null`, causing `null.ToString()` to throw aforementioned exception.

Ensure an `<add key="HK" value="..." />` is in the appsettings section of your relevant configuration.

Comment: You don't need luck but logic. You're not telling what went wrong. You don't tell whether the configuration contains the correct app setting.

Comment: <configuration> <appSettings> <add key="HK" value="PRO2"/> <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/> </appSettings> <startup> <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> </startup> </configuration> This is my app.config file

Comment: But you want to read it from a website. Shouldn't it be `web.config`? Explain your problem better **by editing your question**, explain what project is installed where, what config files they use and how those files are named.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity in my question.
1. key is in App.Config (Windows application)
2. I'm trying to read it in Load event of Home.cs (which is  a startup form in windows application). 
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string url = string.Format("http://localhost:49916/Express/Login.aspx?yek@soh={0}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HK"].ToString());
           Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url);
       }
The above code is working fine in development (VS 2008).

Comment: But when setup created, installed, and tried to run. It is throwing the error at the line where the appsettings key is read.. That's the issue.

Comment: That is not the issue, it is a symptom. You get the exception because your program can't find the configuration data. Make sure the correct file with the correct content is in the correct location, I can't say more than that.

Comment: Thats fine.. Thanks for ur help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the case that you are looking at the wrong app.config? I have done this 100 of times.

Comment: Is the config in the same folder as the application? Is it named correctly? applicationname.extension.config ?when you are debugging the debugger reads the vhost config file instead of the applicationname.extension.config file.

Comment: @user1540857 The OP isn't having a problem at debug time.  Visual studio will copy the app.config to the vhost... file as needed.  It sounds like the installer on the other machine isn't creating the correct file.